# Junit 4 + Eclipse - Run inner class test cases with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner as well

Tags: eclipse, spring, unit-testing, junit4

I need to run inner class test cases from eclipse using Junit4. I understand that there is org.junit.runners.Enclosed that is intended to serve this purpose. It works well for "plain" unit test i.e. without the need for spring context configuration.

For my case, give sample code below, Adding another annotation of Enclosed does not work since there is a conflict of both SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and Enclosed test runners. How can I solve this problem ?

Note: Kindly ignore any basic spelling mistake/basic import issues in the below example since I tried to cook up from my actual use-case.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/unit-test-context.xml"})
public class FooUnitTest {

// Mocked dependency through spring context 
@Inject
protected DependentService dependentService;

 public static class FooBasicScenarios extends FooUnitTest{
   @Test
   public void testCase1 {
   .....
   List<Data> data = dependentService.getData();
    .....
   }
  }


 public static class FooNeagativeScenarios extends FooUnitTest{
   @Test
   public void testCase1 {
   .....
   List<Data> data = dependentService.getData();
    .....
   }
  }
} 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

FooUnitTest is a container, you cannot use it as a superclass.

You need to move all your spring-code to Scenario-classes. And use @RunWith(Enclosed.class). For example, with abstract superclass

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class FooUnitTest {

 @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/unit-test-context.xml"})
 protected abstract static class BasicTestSuit {

   // Mocked dependency through spring context 
   @Inject
   protected DependentService dependentService;
 }

 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 public static class FooBasicScenarios extends BasicTestSuit {
   @Test
   public void testCase1 {
   .....
   List<Data> data = dependentService.getData();
    .....
   }
  }

 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 public static class FooNeagativeScenarios extends BasicTestSuit {
   @Test
   public void testCase1 {
    .....
    List<Data> data = dependentService.getData();
     .....
   }
 }
}
```

Of course you can declare all dependencies in each Scenario-class, in that case there is no necessary in abstract superclass.